# Reading the values in the nested array. JSON

Tags: c#, json

At least I think that's what it is called?
Ultimately I'd like to populate variables with the read values but for now I'm playing with the console to get at the values.
This is C# and what I am trying to do is to read the JSON from a file and then output each "row"
I am able to output the "outer" values, that is the ones that are not part on the nested array (FieldList).
So the code below I get 
251037 406

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("c:\\temp\\crms.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            foreach (var item in array)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.RecordProcessID, item.CallProcessID);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

But if I try to get item.Firstname and item.Surname I get nothing.
Here is a subset of the JSON so you can see the data layout... How can I read the hash values within the FieldList array?

```
[{"RecordProcessID":251037,
"CallProcessID":406,
"FieldList":[{"fieldName":"DateofCall",
"fieldValue":"1/02/2017"
},
{"fieldName":"TimeOfCall",
"fieldValue":"17:14:54"
},
{"fieldName":"Group",
"fieldValue":"Control"
},
{"fieldName":"OperatorName",
"fieldValue":"Jamie"
},
{"fieldName":"Reference",
"fieldValue":"251037"
},
{"fieldName":"RequestType",
"fieldValue":"(Secured)"
},
{"fieldName":"23773",
"fieldValue":"Blue"
},
{"fieldName":"23774",
"fieldValue":"9809"
},
{"fieldName":"FirstName",
"fieldValue":"Jane"
},
{"fieldName":"Surname",
"fieldValue":"Smith"
},
{"fieldName":"CallersAddress",
"fieldValue":"29 Ave,"
},
{"fieldName":"37527",
"fieldValue":"Yes I have done this"
},
{"fieldName":"CallersPhone",
"fieldValue":"123"
},
{"fieldName":"CallersMobile",
"fieldValue":""
},
{"fieldName":"Problemaddress",
"fieldValue":"29 Ave"
},
{"fieldName":"39081",
"fieldValue":""
},
{"fieldName":"CallDetails",
"fieldValue":"Secured"
},
{"fieldName":"PagedTime",
"fieldValue":"1718"
},
{"fieldName":"ReturnCallTime",
"fieldValue":"1721"
},
{"fieldName":"JobAcceptedBy",
"fieldValue":"Fred"
},
{"fieldName":"ProposedActions",
"fieldValue":"Will go have a look"
}
]
},
```

UPDATE - here was my final solution

```
string fieldname = "";
        string fieldvalue = "";
        Dictionary<string, string> myDic = new Dictionary<string, string>(2);

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("c:\\temp\\crms.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            foreach (dynamic item in array)
            {
                myDic.Clear();
                foreach (var field in item.FieldList)
                {
                    fieldname = field.fieldName;
                    fieldvalue = field.fieldValue;
                    myDic.Add(fieldname, fieldvalue);
                }
                insertNewRecord(myDic["FirstName"], myDic["Surname"]);
            }


        }


    }
    public static void insertNewRecord(string firstName, string surname)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", firstName, surname);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: There is no `item.Firstname`, but there is an object where `item.fieldName == "FirstName"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to enumerate thru the list and find the field you want

```
    string firstName, surname;
    foreach(dynamic field in item.FieldList)
    {
        if (field.fieldName == "FirstName")
        {
             firstName = field.fieldValue
        }
        elseif (field.fieldName == "Surname")
        {
             surname = field.fieldValue
        } 
    }
    Console.WriteLine(firstName + ", " + surname);
```

Comment: So rather than query for the existence of FirstName, how can I just output it's value. What would be the way to traverse it to replace item.ProcessID.
Ultimately I want to do something like string firstname = item...FirstName

Comment: foreach (dynamic field in item.FieldList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(field.FieldName);
                    } gives me an error saying {"The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Console.WriteLine(string, params object[])' and 'System.Console.WriteLine(char[])'"}

Comment: Thanks Steve, this got me exactly where I needed to be

Comment: @Penfold just do Console.WriteLine((string) field.fieldVaue)

Comment: I'd like to be able to get a direct handle on a specific fieldname and get the fieldValue for example string fullName = field.FieldName["FirstName"].value + ", " + field.fieldName["Surname"].value.   I know this is invalid but hopefully it illustrates what I'm trying to do

Comment: This one? Console.WriteLine((string) field.fieldVaue) ?

Comment: @Penfold field.fieldVaue is the value of the FirstName. You can store it in a variable and then do the append outside of the loop

Comment: Right. But in order to be able to get the value for a specific field name (e.g. FirstName) I need to query the fieldname of the current field in the loop? There is no way for me to directly reference a fieldname by name (so to speak?). So to get 6 specific field values I'd have 6 separate if statements? Seems a bit long handed but if that is my only choice then so be it. To use the DOM as an analogy I could use document.getElementById("FirstName").InnerHTML - I was looking for a similar jsonpath ability

Comment: @Penfold nope, its your only choice im afraid. Even if you can manage to shorten it to one line it is still doing a foreach loop under the hood

Comment: ok thanks, means I need to do an 'else varName = ""' otherwise I get an unassigned variable error when trying to use the variable outside of the if statement but no problem.

Comment: Got what I needed to do! - no idea how to add it to comments though! Will try to add it to my initial question as an UPDATE

Comment: Any ideas why this question got down voted? Did I violate policy or something? I thanked those who got me where I needed to be and posted the final solution that others may find later. This is affecting my ability to ask more questions so I need to know what constituted a down vote - thanks

Answer (score 1):

I created and tested the following code that you can use:

```
public class SampleListItem
    {
        public string fieldName { set; get; }
        public string fieldValue { set; get; }
    }

    public class Sample 
    { 
        public int RecordProcessID { set; get; }
        public int CallProcessID {set; get; }
        public List<SampleListItem> FieldList { set; get; }
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:\\temp\\crms.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            List<Sample> principalArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sample>>(json);
            foreach (var principalItem in principalArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", principalItem.RecordProcessID, principalItem.CallProcessID);

                foreach (var field in principalItem.FieldList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", field.fieldName, field.fieldValue);

                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

The field name is "fieldName", not "Firstname"